# Display JSON in Javascript from Python Bottle

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, bottle

I am trying to access a mongodb record within a javascript function to display the document on a webpage.  Using the Bottle framework with pymongo, I have tried to first encode the mongodb document as a JSON object to pass to my javascript function.

```
@bottle.route('/view/<_id>', method = 'GET')
def show_invoice(_id):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
    db = client.orders
    collection = db.myorders
    from bson.objectid import ObjectId
    result = collection.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(_id)})
    temp = json.dumps(result,default=json_util.default)
    print "temp: " + temp

    return bottle.template('invoice', rows = temp)
```

When I try to display the document within my HTML page with the javascript function, nothing happens.  However, when I call the variable, rows, that I am trying to pass as {{rows}} within the body of the HTML it does display.  It seems it is only the JS function that does not display anything.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <head>
    <title>Invoice Report</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fillTable()
    {
      var obj = {{rows}};
      document.write(obj);

    }
    </script>
   </head>
  </head>
  <body onload="fillTable()">
     <div class="invoice">
     </div>
     <h4>Rows from body</h4> {{rows}}

  </body>
 </html>
```

I tried to use jQuery to deserialize the JSON object rows with the function

```
jQuery.parseJSON(rows);
```

and even as
    jQuery.parseJSON({{rows}});

I also tried to make the variable unescaped everywhere possible as {{!rows}}
So does anybody see what I am doing wrong? How do I take a mongodb document with pymongo, and use bottle to display it on a webpage? I realize that similar questions have been asked, but I can't seem to get anything I have found to work in my particular situation.

Comment: JSON, if evaluated as javascript _is_ an object. You could either: 1) put it in single quotes and deserialize it or 2) just say `var obj = {{rows}};`

Comment: What is in the HTML page that is sent to the browser?  How does the `fillTable` function look if you do 'view source'?

Comment: function fillTable()
    {document.write({&quot;item1&quot;: &quot;tees&quot;, &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Steve&quot;, &quot;phone&quot;: &quot;(890) 908-8228&quot;, &quot;qyt2&quot;: &quot;180&quot;, &quot;quote&quot;: &quot;250.75&quot;, &quot;qyt1&quot;: &quot;90&quot;, &quot;qty&quot;: &quot;90&quot;, &quot;color1&quot;: &quot;white&quot;, &quot;color&quot;: &quot;black&quot;, &quot;color3&quot;: &quot;red&quot;, &quot;color2&quot;: &quot;grey&quot;, &quot;created&quot;: {&quot;$date&quot;: 1374668193935}, &quot;item&quot;: &quot;shirts&quot;, &quot;item2&quot;: &quot;});
}

Comment: @DanLecocq I just tried to update my fillTable function to var obj = {{rows}}; and then document.write(obj);  But still nothing shows up

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to re-edit the question with the updated information for formatting purposes.

Comment: When I view the page source, the JSON object seems to be there, so is it not possible to display it with document.write()?

Comment: @DanLecocq thank you for your help, I edited the question with the new revisions, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: When debugging like this, I generally use `console.log` (instead of `document.write`) and check the output console to verify I am indeed invoking it as I think I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with bottle rendering your json, it's with using `document.write()`.

Open a new tab in your browser, and point it to the url: 'about:blank'.  This will give you a blank webpage.  Now, right click and open your developer tools.  Try running `document.write('Stuff');` from that context.  You shouldn't see any changes to the page.

Instead try:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.innerHTML = "Stuff";
```

and note the difference.

There are of course, many other ways to achieve this effect, but this is the simplest without any requirements on external javascript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both an 'src' attribute and javascript code in the same  tag. Place the  fillTable function within a new script tag.

Comment: Sorry, that was left from when I tried to use JQuery, but it still won't work after I remove that src attribute.